# Providing alternative resources for all countries using British English

Tags: android, localization

In Android app development, is it possible to provide a single set of alternative resources for **all** countries that *officially* use British English *or* a historically significant variation of it?

For example, assume the default US English strings are provided in:

```
res/values/strings.xml
```

I can provide British English strings (a subset) in:

```
res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml
```

However, this goes by the country code and may only apply to users in Great Britain (UK/GB). I will need to repeat this for every country I know to use British English or its derivative (such as India).

**Does Android provide any qualifier to automatically cover such a scenario?**

Something like:

```
res/values-British/strings.xml
```

where the qualifier `british` is applied to all locales that use a variation of British English as the *lingua franca*.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not. However there is a neutral English

```
res/values-en/strings.xml
```

You can either use this for British English or US English. If you use country neutral English it is always loaded then there is no country specific version. So if you have both

```
res/values-en/strings.xml
res/values-en-rUS/strings.xml
```

and the first contain British English and the second uses US English.

There are more countries using British spelling than US spelling so above solution would be satisfactory for most English users.

Comment: How will the default values (`res/values/strings.xml`) play into this? Which variation should I place there? Also could you cite a source for the statistic *"more countries using British"*? Thanks.

Comment: res/values/strings.xml should be in language that is most likely understod by user in the case the application is not localized for his/her language. Most often this is English. You can choose either British or US English. If you use English as base language wyou don't have to provide res/values-en/strings.xml at all. res/values/strings.xml and res/values-en-rUS/strings.xml (or res/values-en-rGB/strings.xml) are enough.

Comment: I could not find any language statistics on country level but it seems that US English is much widely used in the web compared to British English (http://www.your-translations.com/US-vs-UK_English.PHP)

Comment: The `PHP` in that link needs to be small letters, as in: http://www.your-translations.com/US-vs-UK_English.php ... The version with capital letters throws a 404 Error. Good find btw.